How to check if a variable contains just a path to a file or just the filename
i'm trying to process whether an input contains just a filename or a directory to a file
D:\SYSTEM\System\Quality controlled songs\My drip Confession.flac and My drip Confession.flac
here is what I constructed
#checks if the input is a directory 
if [[ -d $filename ]]; then
    echo "Extracting Filename and Directory: $filename "
    #this extracts the directory of the input
    directory=$(dirname "$filename")

    #this extracts the filename of the input
    filename=$(basename "$filename")

     #this makes the rest of the code execute in the input directory
     cd "$directory"

#checks if the input is a file
elif [[ -f $filename ]]; then
    echo "Extracting Filename: $filename "

else
    echo "Invalid input: $filename "
    exit 1
fi

and when I input D:\SYSTEM\System\Quality controlled songs\My drip Confession.flac it outputs Extracting Filename: $filename when it shouldn't do that since it contains a path
so what do I do?
I just used parameters -d and -f.

Split by Directory Seperator?

Check whether there's a slash or backslash in the string.

You don't need to distinguish it. If there's no directory, dirname will return ., and cd "$dirname" will leave you in the current directory.

Are you trying to write a script to run on Unix or Windows? In case it's Unix - \ isn't the directory separator in Unix, / is. A file name in Unix can contain \.

It's not clear if you want absolute path that already exists or you have the intention to create them

If you want to know whether the user has entered a filename or a path name, the script should be called with the option -f.
A solution to this would be to verify if the user has entered as a first option -f or not using if[ "$1"="-f"];.
Here is a simple solution that I propose to you:
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$1" = "-f" ]; then 
    if [ -n "$2" ]; then
        finalname=$(basename "$2")
        echo "File name is: $finalname "
        filepath=$(dirname "$2")
        echo "File path is: $filepath "
    else
        echo "Please enter a file name after option -f."
    fi
else
    echo "Please use -f"
fi

I hope this answers to your question and I would be glad if anyone could correct my reasoning or add more to this discussion.
Happy coding!

The test -d detects if the target is a directory, not if it contains a directory component. The test -f is true if the target is a file, so your bash output is as expected. If you want to test if the target contains any directory path at all, I'd use this approach:
#!/bin/bash
filename=$(basename $1)
[[ $1 != $filename ]] && echo "Contains a path component"

In short, ask for the filename component of the path and if it isn't the same thing as the filename given, some directory component was stripped by basename. You can try something similar using dirname but it inserts a fake . even if none was given. That makes differentiating foo.txt and ./foo.txt difficult.

[[ -d $filename ]] tests if $filename is a directory, not if $filename contains a directory part.
You can declare a function that uses a bash conditional expression with the =~ operator (regex matching) and the BASH_REMATCH array to do the test and to separate the path components:
do_my_stuff() {
  filename=$1
  if ! [[ -f $filename ]]; then
    printf '%s: file not found\n' "$filename"
    return 1
  fi
  if [[ $filename =~ ^(.*)\\(.*) ]]; then
    directory=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    cd "$directory" || return 1
    filename=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
  fi
  printf 'Extracting Filename: %s\n' "$filename"
}

And then:
do_my_stuff 'D:\SYSTEM\System\Quality controlled songs\My drip Confession.flac'

We first test the existence of file $filename and return with status 1 (error) if $filename does not exist or if it is not a file. Then we use =~ to test if there is a directory part in $filename. If yes we separate the components, we try to cd to the directory and return with status 1 if it fails.
Note: thanks to the returned status you can use the function in a test:
if do_my_stuff "some file name"; then
  <cool>
else
  <oops>
fi

